# htaccess conditional DirectoryIndex based on incoming traffic from certain domains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to show different index pages for surfers coming from different domains.
I would like to set a list of domains, from which the incoming traffic should be directed to a certain index page on my site, then set another list of domains incoming surfers from which should land on a different index page on my site, etc... 
Example:

surfer from `domain1.com`, `domain2.com`, `domain3.com` should land on `indexA.php`

surfer from `domain4.com`, `domain5.com` should land on `indexB.php`

etc..

Help would be appreciated :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HTTP_REFERER` header for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (domain1|domain2|domain3)\.(com|net|org|info)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?$ /indexA.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (domain4|domain5)\.(com|net|org|info)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?$ /indexA.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: thank you, this method also works, and I prefer to use this one. Exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: sorry I was going to ask, if the domain the traffic is coming in from has different extension to .com, like .info, .net, etc, would the code be still okay or I have to append something? Thanks!

Comment: see my updated for supporting `(com|net|org|info)` etc extensions in domain.

Comment: anubhava hello, just have some further clarifying question-

Comment: anubhava hello, just have some further clarifying question- in the brackets where you add the domains, I should not put the extension, should I? Like, what is correct: A - (domain1.com|domain2.com) or B - (domain1|domain2)?  - I also wanted to ask, can I use a full url path to direct traffic to any url, like so: RewriteRule ^/?$ /http://www.domain4.com/indexA.php [L,NC]    or if I want to use full url then some other code has to be used? Sorry if these are noob questinons! Thanks!

Comment: To use full URL in the target you can use for example: `RewriteRule ^/?$ http://domain4.com/indexA.php [L,NC]` And if you want to use full domains in `RewriteCond` then use something like: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (domain4\.com|domain5\.net)`

Comment: Also if this answer has worked for you can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the domains are set up and what kind of access you have. If the domains all have their own VirtualHost configuration and you have access to that configuration (i.e., you can alter the main Apache configuration and restart Apache), you can set the DirectoryIndex for the `domain1.com`, `domain2.com` and `domain3.com` to `indexA.php` and for `domain4.com`, and `domain5.com` to `indexB.php`. If you don't have access to the main Apache config have to use `RewriteRule`s:

```
DirectoryIndex indexA.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain4\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain5\.com$
RewriteRule ^/$ indexB.php [L]
```

That will use `indexA.php` as default index, but use `indexB.php` as index file for `http://domain4.com/` and `http://domain5.com/`

(This is assuming all domains are served from the same directory. If you have separate directories for the different domains you can just put `DirectoryIndex` in their respective `.htaccess` files)

Comment: thank you for your help, this works - yes I have access to .htaccess per domain